# How to properly compare numbers in scientific notation using R?

Tags: r, p-value, proportions

I was reading the [following tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-proportions-z-test-in-r-programming/) for testing proportions in two populations. After running

```
prop.test(x=c(342,290), n=c(400,400))
```

I received a p-value of 9.558674e-06, which the tutorial says is greater than the alpha level of .05. I assumed this was a typo, and was just comparing the p-value to its value in decimal notation, 0.000009558674, but received "False". I even turned off scientific notation using

```
options(scipen=999)
```

and when printing out the p-value from the object returned by prop.test, I still receive "False" when comparing the p-value to 0.000009558674 for equality, it recognizes the p-value as lesser than. Why is this the case?

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you are comparing 9.559e-06 (rounded) to 9.558674e-06, which could be less than or greater than depending on the unrounded value?

Comment: Floating-point *equality* (especially with high precision numbers) should be tested with care; a better comparison is to see if the absolute-difference is below a threshold. For instance, `abs(9.559e-06 - 0.000009558674) < 1e-9` is true, indicating that those numbers are very similar. For floating-point equality, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518, https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the original post. The p-value I received was 9.558674e-06.

Comment: See r2evans answer. Equality of floating point numbers can never really be tested properly.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question.  See the R FAQ:  https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: Thanks for the clarification everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using the `all.equal()` function. The tolerance between the values can be set with the `tolerance` argument.

```
isTRUE(all.equal(2, 2.00000001))
##  [1] TRUE
isTRUE(all.equal(2, 2.00000001, tolerance = 0.0000000001))
##  [1] FALSE
```